# How to add System.Web.Extensions to get JavaScriptSerializer work

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am writing code from .NET to .NETCore project. Getting error in code related to **`System.Web.Extensions.dll`**

This is my code

```
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(reproc);
```

`System.Web.Extensions.dll` is not available in nuget package manager. I have `Newtonsoft.Json` already installed but that doesn't have import for `JavaScriptSerializer`.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to get rid of `JavaScriptSerializer` and use `Newtonsoft.Json` or `System.Text.Json`, which is built-in?

Comment: Tried SerializeObject, its working for me. Thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 0):

As per PavelAnikhouksi Comment. `Newtonsoft.Json`'s `SerializeObject` worked.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reproc);
```